# Can Facebook revert back React license to BSD + Patent License?

Tags: reactjs

I am planning to use React for a project. It's been a controversy in later part of 2017 when Facebook brought react under from BSD + Patent license creating an uproar in the open-source community. Many business had shifted away from using React.

Now that it is maintained under MIT license, is it possible for them to revert back BSD + Patent license in future thus causing problems for new businesses using React?